# NoReverseMatch at /users/password_reset/

Tags: django, smtp, django-urls

I am trying to set up my Password Reset function for my application but getting errors after i send the reset password to my email.

here is the error message: Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' not found. 'password_reset_confirm' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Below is my urls.py codes: `

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('signup/', views.user_signup, name='signup'),
    path('login/', views.user_login, name='login'),
    path('logout/', views.user_logout, name='logout'),
    path('password_reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(), name='password_reset'),
    path('password_reset/done', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(), name='password_reset_done'),
    path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('reset/complete/', auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(), name='password_reset_complete'),
    path('user_profile/<int:id>/', views.user_profile, name='user_profile'),
]`
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably in your template you are using it this way:

```py
{% url 'password_reset_confirm' %}
```

But your URL pattern has a parameter `<uidb64>`, so it has to be something like this:

```py
{% url 'password_reset_confirm' uid %}
```

[Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordResetConfirmView).

Comment: I am yet to add it to the template, trying to run everything from backend before i connect it to the template, let me check the Docs, thanks